# Tell Tab and Space indented files apart

Tags: text-processing, utilities

I was using the `file` command to gather information about some text files (well, XML files, but the XML info did not interest me), but there was one bit of information that I missed in the output: whether the file was indented with tabs or spaces.

Is there any command that will give me that? Or any sort of configuration I can use to get `file` to display that information?

I know I can use `grep -l -P "^\x09"`, for example, but I'm looking for something that already does what I need, and, presumably, already went through all the corner cases I haven't yet thought of.

Comment: The XML format does not care whether the file is indented with spaces or tabs, or not at all, or even if the whole document lives on a single line.

Comment: I'm not sure the spec is complete; does the existence of one tab-indented line count, or do they all have to be tabbed over? If spaces, how many spaces?

Comment: @Kusalananda The XML tools don't care. The person reading XML, which _is_ intended to be human-readable, does.

Comment: I don't think you would be able to find a program for the sole purpose of telling you if a file has tabs in it or not, however to make it simple, I can suggest `cat -A <file> | grep '\^I'`

Answer (score 0):

To detect indentation *properly* in a structured text format, the `file` command would have to implement a proper parser for that format.  The occurrence of the character sequence `\n␣` (newline followed by a space) is not enough to say that the file is indented by spaces as that character sequence could occur inside an XML attribute.

I don't think literal tabs can occur unencoded in XML attributes, but I'm not sure about `CDATA` sections.